# How do I get the angle to which I want to rotate UIView

Tags: objective-c

[image: degrees]

The red line is UIView that is rotating with anchor point at its center. What I want to achieve is that when I drag my finger around that green circle holding it on the red circle, that red line goes along with the finger. But I can't do that without knowing the angle. How do I count it?

Comment: Are you asking for the radius or the degrees?

Comment: you have the radius, it is 152

Comment: I'm asking how to count it every time my finger move and gets different coordinates in the area I described on image (304 width, 140 height)

Comment: you dont count it: you will be informed about touch started, touch moved, touch ended.

Comment: how could radius can change over time? won't it be constant?

Comment: I'm draggin my finger, it's like taking that red circle and dragging it around the green half-circle. The radius of that red line changing over time when I drag it.

Comment: the angle changes. a line has no radius. and the radius of the green circle is constant 152

Comment: I'm sorry, angle. My bad.

Comment: btw: in the coordinate system of UIView (0,0) is in the upper left corner.

Comment: I know, I just needed to get the idea how to count it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the radius. In this case you know that the center of the circle is at x:152, y:0. Your touch location would be at x1, y1, which gives you enough information to calculate the legs.
In code:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(152.0f, 0.0f);
CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:yourView];
float xLeg = fabs(center.x - touchPoint.x);
float yLeg = fabs(touchPoint.y);
angle = atan(xLeg / yLeg);
//float radius = sqrt(pow(xLeg, 2) + pow(yLeg, 2));
```

Hope it helps!

Note: Edited to reflect change of wording. Original question asked for radius.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but this solution wont be able to tell if the angle is left or right from center.

Comment: @ikinciviking You are right. Checking if touchPoint.x is greater than or less than than center.x should do the trick.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Just needed to add - in front of atan, because it was clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

use the arctangent of 3 points. (center, the point, where touch started/ or a fixed position that you define as angle 0 , the current touch point )

```
double AngleBetweenThreePoints(CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2, CGPoint point3)
{
    CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(point2.x - point1.x, -1*point2.y - point1.y *-1);
    CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(point3.x -point1.x, -1*point3.y -point1.y*-1);
    double angle = atan2(p2.x*p1.y-p1.x*p2.x,p1.y*p2.y);        
    return angle /(2* M_PI);
}
```

Comment: +1 good answer.  probably it's good enough for just drawing, but the sign of angle will be a little unstable around zero.  could add a threshold: if (epsilon < angle < epsilon) angle=0;